# Narrations on the virtues of vinegar and dates, are they authentic?

Tags: hadith, source-identification, authenticity, food

I believe to have read or heard in lectures that there are narrations about dates and vinegar of the like "*that whose people's households possess dates* or (in another narration) *vinegar, will not be of the poor people* or something similar in relation with rizq (provision or wealth);

Is this authentic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asalaam Alaikum

there are numerous hadith about the benefits and virtues of dates and vinegar, specially dates in authentic sunnah. there are ahadith with the same concept in which you have mentioned. ill try to clarify to my best ability so that you can have a better understanding, insha Allah.

lets look at ahadith about dates first,

01 - It was narrated from ‘Ubaidullah bin Abu Rafi’, from his grandmother Salma, that the Prophet (ﷺ) said:

“A house in which there are no dates is like a house in which there is no food.”

[Reference: Sunan Ibn Majah 3328]

this hadith is graded 'hasan' by Darussallam.

02 - It was narrated from ‘Aishah that the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said:

“A house in which there are no dates, its people will go hungry.”

[Reference: Sunan Ibn Majah 3327]

this hadith is graded 'sahih' by Darussallam.

03 - 'A'isha reported Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) as saying:

'A'isha a family which has no dates (in their house) its members will be hungry; (or) 'A'isha the family which has no dates its members may be hungry. He said this twice or thrice.

[Reference: Sahih Muslim 2046b]

regarding how we interpret this hadith i would like to mention, It is to be interpreted, according to the scholars, as referring to people whose food includes dates, such as the people of Madeenah at the time of the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) and others whose staple food is dates.

now comming to the hadith about the mentioning of a house without vinegar.

Umm Sa’d said:

“The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) entered upon ‘Aishah, when I was with her, and said: ‘Is there any food?’ She said: ‘We have bread, dates and vinegar.’ The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said: ‘What a blessed condiment vinegar is. O Allah, bless vinegar, for it was the condiment of the Prophets before me, and no house will ever be poor in which there is vinegar.’”

[Reference: Sunan Ibn Majah 3318]

this is hadith is graded 'maudu' by Darussallam.

i believe it is worthy to mention that there are many authentic hadith mentioning that vinegar is a very good condiment,  narrated by Muslim in his Saheeh (2051), and by at-Tirmidhi (1840) and Ibn Maajah (3316).

may Allah grant you mercy and guide you to the straight path, insha Allah.

Allah knows best.

Comment: The same for you, Allahumma Amin!

Comment: Is there only this one hadith from Ibn Majah about vinegar in relation to poverty? Are there more or just this fabricated one?

Comment: i did not find any other in the chapter of food from ibn Majah, only this one in relation to vinegar and poverty.
may Allah help me if i am mistaken.